# What does numeric operations mean in a sum in sql expression?

Tags: sql-server

```
SUM(rating IN (4.5, 5))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_5_star,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating IN (4.5, 5) THEN rating ELSE 0 END) AS in_5_star
```

I don't know why I am finding it difficult to understand what exactly is happening in the above statement and what exactly is `/COUNT(*)*100` doing here.

Comment: Expressing percentage as a whole number (54% instead of 0.54). This is something the presentation tier could do instead of SQL Server, of course.

Comment: The expression `SUM(rating IN (4.5, 5))` is not valid in SQL Server and would result in an error. Did you get this query from another DBMS (eg MySQL) that converts the boolean result (`rating IN (4.5, 5)`) to integer for the SUM function to process?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Agreed.  I thought we'd all stumbled upon a magical new shortcut :)  I was disappointed when I tried it in my environment.

Comment: @MguerraTorres it would indeed be magical when (and if) SQL Server has boolean datatype implemented ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ then I wouldn't have a reason to use BIT!  BIT needs love too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COUNT(*)*100 in this scenario seems to be how the developer dynamically gets the percentage based on how many records are returned.

Maybe it's better read this way:

```
((
    SUM(rating IN (4.5,5)) --SUM of ratings of 4.5 and 5
    /  --divided by
    COUNT(*)  --The total number of records
  )
*100) --Multiplied by 100 to make it readable as a percentage
AS pct_5_star
```

So if the query returns 100 records, it divides the SUM by 100 then multiplies thatresult by 100 to get an easily readable number.

if the query returns 150 records, it divides the SUM by 150 then multiplies that result by 100 to get an easily readable number.

Answer (score 0):

You leave a lot to be deduced.  The select is querying a set containing ratings from 0 or 1 to 5, including half points.  So, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, ... 4, 4.5 and 5.   pct_5_star gives the percentage of ratings 4.5 and 5 on the total of ratings, in_5_star the exact number.